# Bluemix Container shutdown issue

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I am trying to use containers for deploying a Fortran based code. I have successfully created an image repository for Fortran environment. However, when I am trying to use the container, the container does not start. It keeps building and never stops after timeout.

I checked for solution online and it was suggested that this happens due to size issue. However, I even tried allocating 2 GB memory (max permissible in my case) and still I am not able to get the container working.

Can someone suggest a solution for this?

```
The result for cf ic inspect

[
    {
        "BluemixApp": null,
        "BluemixServices": null,
        "Config": {
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "Cmd": [],
            "Dns": "",
            "Env": [
                "logging_password=",
                "space_id=09b438a1-16ea-4e78-9229-6c8ff48522bd",
                "logstash_target=logmet.opvis.bluemix.net:9091",
                "metrics_target=logmet.opvis.bluemix.net:9095"
            ],
            "Hostname": "instance-01024a2b",
            "Image": "registry.ng.bluemix.net/legacycontainer/madeline-chat:latest",
            "ImageArchitecture": "amd64",
            "Labels": {
                "doc.url": "/docs/images/docker_image_ibmnode/ibmnode_starter.html"
            },
            "Memory": 1024,
            "MemorySwap": "",
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "PortSpecs": "",
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Tty": true,
            "User": "",
            "VCPU": 1,
            "VolumesFrom": "",
            "WorkingDir": ""
        },
        "ContainerState": "Networking",
        "Created": "2016-11-15T05:15:14.000000000Z",
        "Group": {},
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "CapAdd": [],
            "CapDrop": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "Links": [],
            "LogConfig": {
                "Config": {},
                "Type": "json-file"
            },
            "LxcConf": [],
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false
        },
        "HostId": "",
        "Human_id": "fortcontainer",
        "Id": "5c3e7369-15f2-4c4c-a032-c7eaafe51057",
        "Image": "sha256:64b79347416c1909ecaf24276c2b37a093c017f03986bd928ce7af29f6e4362e",
        "Mounts": [],
        "Name": "fortcontainer",
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "IPAddress": "172.31.0.14",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "fa:16:3e:c3:62:6d",
            "Networks": {
                "default": {
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "EndpointID": "5c3e7369-15f2-4c4c-a032-c7eaafe51057",
                    "Gateway": "172.31.0.1",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "IPAddress": "172.31.0.14",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "Links": null,
                    "MacAddress": "fa:16:3e:c3:62:6d",
                    "NetworkID": "01f0a8a5-782c-40c3-a9c9-6fb1f2b338ab"
                }
            },
            "PortMapping": null,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "169.44.117.254",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "PublicIpAddress": "169.44.117.254"
        },
        "Path": "date",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/etc/resolv.conf",
        "State": {
            "Error": "Unable to start container",
            "ExitCode": -1,
            "Fault": {
                "code": 500,
                "created": "2016-11-15T05:16:17Z",
                "message": "Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance 5c3e7369-15f2-4c4c-a032-c7eaafe51057. Last exception: [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\\n', u'  File \"/opt/bbc/openstack-12.1.90/nova/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
            },
            "FinishedAt": "2016-11-15T05:16:17.000000000Z",
            "Ghost": "",
            "Pid": 1,
            "Running": false,
            "StartedAt": "2016-11-15T05:15:14.000000000Z",
            "Status": "Networking"
        },
        "Volumes": {},
        "VolumesRW": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get some additional information about the container, either through `cf ic logs` (if the container was running, just not going active), or `cf ic inspect` (if the container doesn't get far enough for that.  Do either of those show any further information about what might be happening here?

Comment: I have added the output of cf ic inspect. Can this happen because I am just trying to run a Hello World fortran executable (using the madeline-chat example as reference) and the image might be executing it and then the container is not expected to do anything.

Comment: @N Fritze I got the issue. When I upload it my dockerfile contains the command to execute the fortran exe. So it is executing the fortran exe and stopping. I guess I will have to create a web page that will interact with fortran exe and stay alive. Thank you for the response.

Comment: That makes sense.  If the fortran program is completing and exiting, it would be expected for the container to exit as well.  Putting in a web server that shells out the fortran program and returns (but stays up to accept future requests and continue doing same) sounds like a good design to handle it.  here's hoping that goes well!